# How to join SQL Tables including the none existing relations

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, rdbms

I have a SQL Server join question.

I have 3 tables:

- one stores the restaurants
- one stores "restaurant properties" like, "Wifi, Pool, Clean, All-Inclusive ..."
- and one stores the relationships between a restaurant and the properties it has

In the end, I want to get a result table for one given restaurant which should list all the properties this restaurants **HAS AND DOES NOT HAVE**. So I need to output null values too.

```
| id     name         |    | idRes   idProp |  | id      prop  |
+---------------------+    +----------------+  +---------------+
| 01     restaurant-01|    | 1        1     |  | 1       wifi  |
| 02     restaurant-02|    | 1        2     |  | 2       pool  |
                           | 2        2     |  | 3       24/7  |
                           | 2        2     |  | 4       clean |
```

Now I want to output the restaurant with the ID 1 with all properties it has and does not have.

```
| id     name           idRes   idProp    id   prop  |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 1      restaurant-1     1       1        1   wifi  |
| 1      restaurant-1     1       2        2   pool  |
| 1      restaurant-1     NULL    NULL     3   24/7  |
| 1      restaurant-1     NULL    NULL     4   clean |
```

I hope that this is even possible. Thank guys in advance. You are awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to know for all properties combined with the restaurant whether a relation exists. So cross join restaurants and properties and outer join the relations:

```
select *
from restaurant r
cross join property p
left join relation rp on rp.idres = r.id and rp.idprop = p.id
where r.id = 1;
```

Comment: Thank You Herr Kettner. You saved my night.